# How to put logic into Rails helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view where I am trying to check if a field in a table is present, and if so, print just that field.  If not, it should print the text: "(none)".  In my view I have:

```
<%=  list_fields(feed) %>
```

And in my helper file I have:

```
    def list_fields(feed)
        feed.xml_fields.each do |field|
            if field.tags?
                field.tags
            else
                puts "(none)"
            end
        end
    end
```

Right now this displays the entire table row for each field object if it has tags, and "[]" if it has no tags.  I just want the individual tags entry to display or "(none)".  What am I missing in my helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems. The first one is that your helper **does not return** the value which could be included in the view by the `<%= ... %>` construct.

The `.each` call returns the object on which it has been called, in this case it would be `feed.xml_fields`, and it does NOT return the individual values calculated by the block.

The second problem is that **`puts` in Rails does not place the text in the rendered view** - it is not PHP.

I am not very confident what exact output you expect, but if you want to return the first 'field' which has 'tags', then you can do this:

```ruby
def list_fields(feed)
  f = feed.xml_fields.detect {|field| field.tags? }
  f ? f.tags : "(none)"
end
```

If you want to list all the tags, and to return the string "(none)", if there are no tags, then use something like this:

```ruby
def list_fields(feed)
  f = feed.xml_fields.select {|field| field.tags? }.map {|field| field.tags }
  f.empty? ? "(none)" : f.join(", ")
end
```

If you want to join the fields with some HTML markup, like a `<br/>`, then use this:

```ruby
def list_fields(feed)
  f = feed.xml_fields.select {|field| field.tags? }.map {|field| h(field.tags) }
  f.empty? ? "(none)" : f.join("<br/>").html_safe
end
```

Note that there are **two** changes: the individual `tags` values are escaped by the `h` function, and then the joined string is marked as being already sanitized. In this case the view will not escape the string again.

If you really want to use something like `puts` in views or helpers, then you may read about the method [concat](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat).

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to accomplish the latter of your suggestions.  I'm a bit confused on the syntax though.  With that `f.join(", ")`, I actually want them joined so that each prints on a newline.  I tried both `f.join("\n")` and `f.join("<br>")` to no avail.

Comment: I have updated the answer. The last example shows how to place HTML tags in the string returned by helper.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your function in such a way:

```
def list_fields(feed)
    feed.xml_fields.each do |field|
        if field.tags?
            return field.tags
        else
           return "(none)"
        end
    end
end
```

There are 2 changes:

- No put in the helper
- return from the loop. The result of an `each`-loop is the array itself, so at the end, it will be returned in your version anyway.

I do not understand why you do the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Return strings from your helper, instead of using `puts`. I don't know what format `field.tags` is, but my guess is it's an array. Format the string how you want it and just return it from the helper.

Something like:

```
def list_fields(feed)
  feed.xml_fields.each do |field|
    if field.tags?
       "some string"
    else
       "(none)"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `field.tags` is a string. Even just putting "some string" after the conditional doesn't change whats actually printed to screen.  It's always the entire `field` array, rather than just `field.tags`.

Comment: oh, derp, because `each` is returning `feed.xml_fields`. set a variable and return that at the end.